# Android JSONArray inside a JSONObject - type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

Im trying to get Data from a JSONObject that contains an array of user details

Im trying to get the username from this json

[JSON Data](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.saveme.ie/posts/)

I can get the top level data easily with

```
JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
Comment saving = new Comment();
saving.set_id(obj.getString("_id"));
saving.setDetail(obj.getString("details"));
saving.setVotes(obj.getInt("votes"));
```

How do i get the username value?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use GSON or LoganSquare?

Comment: get the user first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username key is again nested inside the JSON object you have in obj.
What you can do is

```
String username = obj.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
obj.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
```

In yours IDE if you will press **ctrl+space**  after **obj**  with a dot (.) operator ,  you should get auto fill with various option to select .

the basic difference between JSONObject and JSONArray is following :

JSONArray starts with []
JSONObject starts with {}

As you can see the **user**  is a JSONObject ,  hence obj.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");

I prefer decoding JSON like this instead of using third party library